# Playing Percussion instruments with midi on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, midi

I have an app that handles playing multiple midi instruments. Everything works great except for playing percussion instruments. I understand that in order to play percussion in General MIDI you must send the events to channel 10. I've tried a bunch of different things, and I can't figure out how to get it to work, here's an example of how I'm doing it for melodic instruments vs percussion.

```
    // Melodic instrument
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, 0x90, (UInt8)pitch, 127, 0);

    // Percussion Instruments
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, 0x99, (UInt8)pitch, 127, 0);
```

The sampler Unit is an `AudioUnit` and the pitch is given as an int through my UI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those two lines of code look fine. Are you using AUSampler or AUMIDISynth? Is the problem that the percussion sounds are silent, or do you see an error message somewhere?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Using AUSampler, and the output when I set the channel to 10 is just the same as channel 1

Comment: Have you loaded a soundfont? As far as I know, AUSampler just uses sine wave tones on iOS unless you load a soundfont yourself.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I'm using a soundfont, Fluid. The instruments all sound great, it just doesn't seem like the reserved channel 10 is doing what it should.

Comment: Are you sending any program change or bank select messages?

Comment: @CL. No, I don't think so. I'm not even sure what you mean.

Comment: So how are you selecting instruments?

Comment: @CL. Through the UI, I have buttons that set self.samplerUnit which is an enum of type NSInteger. It has the 128 standard sounds. So is there a specific instrument I need to choose alongside sending to channel 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it working. I guess the way I load the sound font makes it so the channel stuff doesn't do anything. Instead I had to set the `bankMSB` property on `AUSamplerBankPresetData` to `kAUSampler_DefaultPercussionBankMSB` instead of `kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB`

I added a different font loading method specifically for percussion:

```
- (OSStatus) loadPercussionWithSoundFont: (NSURL *)bankURL {
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    // fill out a bank preset data structure
    AUSamplerBankPresetData bpdata;
    bpdata.bankURL  = (__bridge CFURLRef) bankURL;
    bpdata.bankMSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultPercussionBankMSB;
    bpdata.bankLSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB;
    bpdata.presetID = (UInt8) 32;

    // set the kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank property
    result = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.samplerUnit,
                                  kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  0,
                                  &bpdata,
                                  sizeof(bpdata));

    // check for errors
    NSCAssert (result == noErr,
               @"Unable to set the preset property on the Sampler. Error code:%d '%.4s'",
               (int) result,
               (const char *)&result);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of a *General MIDI* sound font or similar loaded, you need to set the correct status byte before sending pitch/velocity information. So in case of a Standard MIDI Drum Kit (channel 9), you'd do something like this in Swift:

```
var status  = OSStatus(noErr)
let drumCommand = UInt32( 0xC9 | 0 )
let noteOnCommand = UInt32(0x90 | channel)
status = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self._samplerUnit, drumCommand, 0, 0, 0) // set device
status = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self._samplerUnit, noteOnCommand, noteNum, velocity, 0)  // sends note ON message
```

No need to undertake anything special for MIDI *note off* messages.

Comment: So I'm actually writing the MIDI part of the app in objective C. I tried this:
<pre>
   UInt32 drumCommand = 0xC9 | 0;
   UInt32 noteOnCommand = 0x90 | 0x99;
   MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, drumCommand, 0, 0, 0);
   MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteOnCommand, (UInt8)pitch, 127, 0);

But it still just plays the regular instrument sounds. And I do have a General MIDI sound font loaded.

Comment: Now you need to make sure that you actually set the NOTE ON command (for drums) to the correct channel! Note that the _correct_ channel number is **9** and not 10 (since they start at zero). So in the above code, if your _channel_ is _9_, then `status = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self._samplerUnit, noteOnCommand, pitch, velocity, 0)` should give you what you need (immediately after instrument setup).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if something is going wrong somewhere else. It's still playing a different instrument. Maybe it has to do with the `AUSamplerBankPresetData` being set when I load the sound font.

Comment: Can be.. If it helps, I had trouble with the _componentSubType_ and I achieved by setting it to _kAudioUnitSubType_MIDISynth_ in the sampler Unit Description...

Comment: Ok, so I got it working. I guess the way I load the sound font makes it so the channel stuff doesn't do anything. Instead I had to set the `bankMSB` property on `AUSamplerBankPresetData` to `kAUSampler_DefaultPercussionBankMSB` instead of `kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB`